# Looking for advice on how site incorporates dynamic URLS

Tags: jquery, html, url

I was interested to know how [this site](http://qz.com/47651/if-the-uks-economy-is-so-lousy-how-come-its-job-market-is-doing-so-well/) goes about incorporating the dynamic URL even though the page doesn't refresh. For example as you scroll down the page the url changes as the story changes, I can imagine that it is done using jquery/ajax.

I am wondering how this might effect things like SEO and how Google might interpret this site. Can Google recognize when the URL changes even though the page has not refreshed? Is there a programming method that notifies Google that the URL has changed as it is spidering the page.

Comment: google doesn't need to know about changes in that page from script... rest assured there are links within site for every one of those url's that bots can find

Comment: Are you talking about sitemaps? Completely forgot about that!

Comment: not just sitemaps, every url has links to several other articles, there are nav links, share links etc

Comment: Ok, so is it safe to say then that Google isn't going to be able to read dynamic url's as they appear on this site? Instead they are relying on more traditional links to identify the pages.

Comment: Just taken a look using inspector and it appears that there is only ever 1 article initially loaded. As the user then begins to scroll a new article is dynamically generated and placed below the previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such navigation could be done with history API, using jnavigate plugin, for example.
Navigation links have onClick event handlers that load content using AJAX, and have "href" property defined for loading page not using AJAX. And Google's spider collects that URLs, and indexes content of related pages. So, its good both for user, and for SEO.